# import modules python script does not run in processBuilder java

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, docker, processbuilder

I am invoking python scripts through processBuilder as below.

```java
        try{
            LOGGER.info("Starting python script execution");
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash");
            Process p = processBuilder.start();
            inp = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
            out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()) );
            err = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()) );

            Thread errorThread = new Thread(new LogScriptErrors(err, errorString));
            errorThread.start();

            out.write("ulimit -v " + MAX_LIMIT + "\n");
            out.write("/usr/bin/python3 " + pythonFile.getAbsolutePath() + " " + inputCsv.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
            Thread readThread = new Thread(new ReadScriptOutput(inp, outputCsv));
            readThread.start();

            if(p.isAlive()) {
                out.newLine();
                out.flush();
            }
            readThread.join();
            errorThread.join();
            p.destroy();
            logScriptErrors(errorString);
            LOGGER.info("Completed python script-based grouping");
        } catch (IOException e){
```

I tried with multiple scripts.
These scripts are working (printing output)

```py
print("starting")
```

```
import sys

given_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

lines = given_file.readlines()
sum = 0

for line in lines:
    for c in line:
        if c.isdigit() == True:
            sum = sum + int(c)

print("sum: ")
print(sum)
given_file.close()
```

But these scripts are not working (not printing any output or error)

```py
import sys
import pandas

def read():
    print("starting")
    file = sys.argv[1]
    print("reading")

    # read_data_from_csv
    df = pandas.read_csv(file)
    print("read")
    print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read()
```

```py
import sys
import numpy

print("starting")
print(numpy.arange(2, 100, 5))

file = sys.argv[1]
print("reading")
```

Seems like when I import something like pandas, numpy - this case occurs

To add more context, this python program is running in kubernetes containers.
I have in installed libraries in containers. This is the content of dockerfile.

```
RUN yum -y install python3.7.4; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python3-pip; yum clean all

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7.4 1
RUN update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.7.4

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN pip3 install pandas
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install scikit-learn
```

Comment: You don't call `p.waitFor()` [ replace destroy] so you have no info on the process status and no info on error messages if you omit code for the STD IO consumers.

Comment: @DuncG could be possible.  But other programs like reading a file is working. It's just when I import pands/numpy (no matter whether I use it not not), it stops working.